# Corpus of English text with tagged locations

Tags: data-request, nlp, text

I'm looking for corpora of English texts with locations tagged.

I am aware of [CONLL2002](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2002/ner/). This is the type of corpus I'm looking for, but want more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [1,108,558 English Wikipedia articles](https://tools.wmflabs.org/templatecount/index.php?lang=en&namespace=10&name=Coord#bottom) that have location information.  Location information is specified by [Template:Coord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Coord) in Wikipedia and can be easily extracted from the text.

I guess this might be the largest free dataset that you can get with your requirements.

Comment: That's a really good idea!